# Confidence intervals for Tobit model in package AER in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, forecasting, prediction, tobit-regression

I use a Tobit model to predict censored data. I use the `AER` package in R.

A toy example looks as follows:

```
library(AER)
N = 10
f = rep(c("s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8"),N)
fcoeff = rep(c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-5,-10,-5),N)
set.seed(100) 
x = rnorm(8*N)+1
beta = 5
epsilon = rnorm(8*N,sd = sqrt(1/5))
y.star = x*beta+fcoeff+epsilon ## latent response
y = y.star 
y[y<0]<-0 ## censored response

my.data = data.frame(x,f)
fit <- tobit(y~0+x+f,data=my.data)

my.range = range(y,y.star,predict(fit))
plot(y,ylim = my.range)
lines( ifelse(predict(fit)>0,predict(fit),0),col="red")
```

The values returned by `predict(fit)` give me the expected value under the model. How can I derive a e.g. 90% confidence interval around this expected value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed previously in [Censored regression in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149091/censored-regression-in-r/149529#149529) the `predict()` method predicts the expectation of the latent uncensored variable `y.star`, not the expectation of the censored variable `y`. So simply cutting at 0 as you do might not be the ideal solution.

Regarding the prediction interval: You can set `predict(fit, se.fit = TRUE)` as you would do in `predict.glm()` to obtain the estimated standard error of the prediction.

This behavior is inherited from the `survreg` infrastructure that is called internally. See `help("predict.survreg", package = "survival")` for more details and further options.

Comment: Thank you (once again) for the explanation. I remember the discussion back then. I just had the impression that the usual predict better fits the observations. I have to go through my script and you explanation again ... thanks a lot!