# Confidence intervals for the coefficients of a Tobit model

Tags: confidence-interval, tobit-regression

Given a linear regression model for a dependent variable that is left-censored at 0 (i.e., a Tobit model), how can I calculate confidence intervals for the coefficients?

Ideally, you would provide code for use with the R package `censReg`, but I ought to be able to implement an algorithm myself given a clear description.

(N.B. The similarly titled question "[Confidence intervals for Tobit model in package AER in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169184/confidence-intervals-for-tobit-model-in-package-aer-in-r)" is actually about prediction intervals for the dependent variable, not confidence intervals for the coefficients.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example from censReg:

```
# Run analysis
  library(censReg)
  data( "Affairs", package = "AER" )
  estResult <- censReg( affairs ~ age + yearsmarried + religiousness +
    occupation + rating, data = Affairs )

# Standard errors
  se <- diag(-solve(estResult$hessian))^0.5

# Data frame with confidence intervals
  clTable <- data.frame(Estimates=estResult$estimate,
    lowerCL = estResult$estimate - 1.96*se,
    upperCL = estResult$estimate + 1.96*se)
  clTable

               Estimates    lowerCL     upperCL
(Intercept)    8.1741974  2.8009641 13.54743072
age           -0.1793326 -0.3343553 -0.02430983
yearsmarried   0.5541418  0.2904867  0.81779697
religiousness -1.6862205 -2.4775735 -0.89486745
occupation     0.3260532 -0.1726193  0.82472575
rating        -2.2849727 -3.0843154 -1.48563000
```

Comment: The first-principles approach is commendable, but I think you can just `confint(estResult, level=0.95)`.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Can't beat that!  (+1)

Comment: You answered my question as I wrote it, but is there an approach that's correct for finite samples, as opposed to this asymptotic method?

Comment: Kodiologist:  You might want to change your mind about accepting my answer.  Your edit inserted the more elegant and succinct code of @DimitriyV.Masterov and I can't take apparent credit for that.

Comment: Take credit, by all means.

Comment: @Kodiologist The usual solution to asymptotic approximation is to use the bootstrap.