# What is the function computed by this zero inflation model?

Tags: r, regression, zero-inflation

Consider this made-up data

```
require(ggplot2)
require(pscl)
require(visreg)

set.seed(23)
y = c(1005,987,784,1487,0,13,1340,451,0,784,0,451,0,0,123,754, 0, 320,0,12,0,0,87,0,0,0)
d = data.frame(
    y = y,
    x = 1:length(y) + runif(length(y),0,2)
)
ggplot(d, aes(y=y,x=x)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

I am running a zero inflation model on this data

```
m = zeroinfl(y~x, dist='negbin', data=d)
print(m)
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = y ~ x, data = d, dist = "negbin")

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
(Intercept)            x  
     7.4524      -0.1054  
Theta = 1.181 

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
(Intercept)            x  
    -2.3405       0.1453
```

With these four estimates, it should be possible to compute a function to display but I am not sure how. What is my function computed by the zeroinfl function?

When I try to plot the model I get

```
visreg(m)
```

[image]

Feels about right. What function is this?

Answer (score 1):

The function is simply expectation of the zero-inflation model, see Equation 8 in `vignette("countreg", package = "pscl")`. This is what `?predict.zeroinfl` computes by default (see also Appendix C in the vignette).

To make sure you can try:

```
visreg(m)
points(d$x, predict(m))
```

[image: expectation-zeroinfl model]

However, the data do not really seem to be count data (or if they are the counts are so large that they are almost continuous). Thus, instead of a zero-inflated count model one could also simply use a Gaussian linear regression, censored at zero (aka tobit model). As pointed out in the post [Censored regression in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149091/censored-regression-in-r) the model can be fitted with the `AER` package (interfacing the `survreg` package) and then one can compute the latent mean, the conditional mean, and the unconditional mean of the response:

```
library("AER")
fit <- tobit(y ~ x, data = d)
mu <- fitted(fit)
sigma <- fit$scale
p0 <- pnorm(mu/sigma)
lambda <- function(x) dnorm(x)/pnorm(x)
ey0 <- mu + sigma * lambda(mu/sigma)
ey <- p0 * ey0
```

This yields the following curves for the latent mean (red) and the unconditional mean (blue):

```
plot(y ~ x, data = d)
abline(fit, col = 2, lwd = 2)
lines(d$x, ey, col = 4, lwd = 2)
```

[image: expectation-tobit]

A heteroscedastic version of the tobit model is also available in the `crch` package.